# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown' with VueJs For Loop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

all inside

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
```

I have this interface

```
interface Ms {
    id: number;
    username: string;
}
```

with this list

```
const list: Ms[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: 'mic',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: 'mac',
    },
]
```

now in vue js what I am trying to do is print all of them in anchor

```
<a v-for="m in list" :key="m.id" :href="m.id">{{ m.name }}</a>
```

and all is working fine with no problem except that my IDE (VSCode) keeps giving me an error on `m.id` and `m.name` telling me

```
const m: unknown
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

const m: unknown
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
```

I can work around it using m['id'] but that only a work around while I want a solution to it.

Comment: Try `(m as Ms).name`

Comment: @Tolbxela does solve but I assume I will have more than id and name, up to 10 parts, do I have to apply this to every usage?

Comment: Are you using volar extension?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your type, it should be 'username' instead of 'name'.

```html
<a>{{ m.username}}</a>
```

Secondly, the href attribute of the 'a' tag requires a value of type string, but your 'id' is of type number.

Answer (score 0):

If there are fewer fields of m object, you can use **(m as Ms).id**, **(m as Ms).name**.

If there are more fields：

```
const list: any[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: 'mic',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: 'mac',
    },
]
```

Comment: didn't change it